# A population with normal distribution, with mean $167$ and standard deviation $3$

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that stature of men in a population with normal distribution has mean $167$cm and standard deviation $3$cm.
Assume that $100$ men are chosen from this population independently.

Question :

1. Find the probability that at least $55$ person's stature is less than  $167$cm.
2. Find the probability that the mean  of their statures is more than $167.6$cm.

Note : My problem is that i don't know how to relate standard deviation and mean, to the probabilities that question wants. Actually, this is a question that one of my relatives asked me and i didn't know how to solve... So i put it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ denote the height of a person. Then you want $$\mathbb{P}(H<167)=\mathbb{P}(Z<\frac{167-167}{3})=1/2$$
Where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable. 
Now you can use $\mu = np$ and $\sigma ^2=np(1-p)$, where $p=1/2$ to figure out the mean and standard deviation of your sample for use in a normal approximation to the binomial distribution. 

This can be done as follows
$$\mu = 100(\frac 12)=50 \quad \sigma = \sqrt{100(\frac 12)(1-\frac 12)}=5$$
Then you need (letting $N$ denote the number of people taller than $167$) $\mathbb{P}(N \ge 55)\approx \mathbb{P}(N > 55-0.5)=1-\mathbb{P}(Z < \frac{55-0.5-50}{5})=1-\mathbb{P}(Z<0.9)\approx 0.18$

For the other question it should be the same procedure with different numbers.